# Jackson based IDE for programming

Tags: programming, ide, gui, graph-theory, flowcharts

Is there any [Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_structured_programming) based IDE for programming?

[image]

I mean, an IDE in which you can place the sentences in sequence from left to right.

I am looking for something similar to [PSeInt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pseint/) (spanish), although PSeInt has only Flowchart classic and Nassi-Shneiderman, you can put similar programs in the comments.

The following is a snapshot of PSeInt with classic flowchart
[image: Classic Flowchart]

And also I have the following example
[image: Classic Flowchart Example 2]
Also you can convert the chart to a Nassi-Shneiderman chart, which will look as follow
[image: Nassi-Shneiderman Flowchart]

Comment: Hi, is this for a teaching experience? If not, this might be a more appropriate question for [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Ben I. this is for both, teaching and learning

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you'd like an IDE like this for teaching purposes? While we sometimes can answer questions about tools for teachers, this doesn't seem specific to teaching CS and may be a better fit elsewhere on the stack exchange network.

Comment: Just to add on to what @thesecretmaster is saying, no need to elaborate here in the comments; please edit the question instead, as the comments will eventually be cleared as a matter of housekeeping.

Comment: Are you looking for a graphical tool that will draw the program in this form?